# Invalid JSON errors from JQuery with ColdFusion CFC, even with seemingly correct JSON returned

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, jquery, cfc

I was looking at Ben's example @ http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1515-Ask-Ben-Building-An-AJAX-jQuery-And-ColdFusion-Powered-Application.htm and wokring on an ultra simplistic example of my own. but it seems like even though the CFC returns properly formatted JSON, it always ends up in my error handler with the error :

```
Invalid JSON: {"ERRORS":"","SUCCESS":true,"DATA":"id DEX015-002-00, whs W1, qty 9"}
```

Here's the ajax call

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'bridge.cfc',
  data: {
    method: 'UpdateQty',
    id: 'DEX015-002-00',
    whs: 'W1',
    qty: '9'
  },
  dataType:'json',
  success: function(res, status, req){ alert("Message from server:\n" + "res: " + res); },
  error: function(req, status, err){ "Error from server:\n" + "err: " + err); }
});
```

And heres the CFC "bridge.cfc"

```
<cfcomponent>
<cffunction name="UpdateQty" access="remote" returntype="struct" returnformat="json"  output="false">
    <cfargument name="id" required="yes" type="string">
    <cfargument name="whs" required="yes" type="string">
    <cfargument name="qty" required="yes" type="string">
    <cfset res = structNew()>
    <cfset res.success = true>
    <cfset res.data = "id " & arguments.id & ", whs " & arguments.whs & ", qty " & arguments.qty >
    <cfset res.errors = "">
    <cfreturn res >
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually when I run into this issue, it's because I have debugging set to output, and it gets tacked on to my remote method's output.

Try adding:

```
<cfsetting showDebugOutput="no" />
```

to your `UpdateQty` method.

Comment: fantastic .. it was driving me crazy.. but that was the trick.. thanks buddy !

Answer (score 3):

Try adding output=false to your cfcomponent.

Comment: thx for the suggestion .. tried that. it should probably be there anyways...but no luck though !

Comment: Can you post this online so we can hit it with our browsers and see the response ourselves?